# codeigniter encryption key to save in external file and set in encrypt library.

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i need the codeigniter encryption library encryption key to set form external file because i dont want this to set in config.php file because of security.

```
 $config['encryption_key'] = 'my_key';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new config file `application/config/config1.php`.with

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'my_key';
```

Now load it form `application/config/autoload.php` as below:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('config1');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Loading custom config file :-

After create custom config file we need to load it get it’s items. for load custom config we have two ways.

1. Manual loading :- we can manual load config file in controller/model like

   ```
    $this->config->load('file_name'); //or use custom_config instead of file_name
   ```

where “file_name” is your custom config file name without .php extension.

2. Autoloading :- for auto load config file go to “application/config/autoload.php” and add code in $autoload[‘config’]

   ```
   $autoload['config'] = array('config_custom'); //where config_custom is your file name.
   ```